# How to change the password of an encrypted LVM system (previously alternate Installation, now advanced feature)?

Tags: password, encryption, lvm, luks, cryptsetup

I installed Ubuntu 11.10 with the **alternate** CD and encrypted the whole system (except boot) with the encrypted LVM. **Update 2020**: Encrypted LVM can be selected at the *Installation type* step of the Ubuntu install, click on ***Advanced features*** and choose *Use LVM* and *Encrypt* ...

Everything works great as before, but I would like to change the password of the encrypted LVM. I tried to follow the Tips and Tricks of this [article](http://blog.andreas-haerter.com/2011/06/18/ubuntu-full-disk-encryption-lvm-luks#tips_and_tricks), but it does not work. 
After typing:

```
sudo cryptsetup luksDump /dev/sda5
```

It says: "Device /dev/sd5 doesn't exist or access denied."
I thought the encrypted partition is /dev/sda5.
Any help how to change the password?

Comment: Oops, it was indeed a typo! I always typed /dev/sd5 instead of /dev/sd5. Thanks Hamish for the hint. So I answer the question with the information from Andreas Härter (blog.andreas-haerter.com/2011/06/18/ubuntu-full-disk-encryption-lvm-luks#tips_and_tricks)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change LUKS passphrase?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/95137/how-to-change-luks-passphrase)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change LUKS passphrase?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/95137/how-to-change-luks-passphrase)

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' Yes, they're duplicate questions, but this question has better answers, so I voted to close the other question as a duplicate of this question instead of close voting in the reverse direction, even though the other question was asked first.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' Thank you for bringing this up. I understand your reasoning and the questions are very similar. Mine was aimed for a command line answer and the other one for a GUI. I agree with karel that this question has better and more detailed answers. But maybe both questions can stay as they are both highly appreciated by the community. Thanks for kindly considering this!

Comment: @Filbuntu Whether or not we close one of these questions as a duplicate of the other, they both can--and should--stay, as both of them and their answers are clearly valuable. (Questions can be closed as duplicates without ever being deleted.)

Answer (score 119, accepted):

## Using the Disks application:

In **Ubuntu 18.04** or newer there is the possibility of using **(Gnome) Disks**. Thanks for the [hint](https://askubuntu.com/a/1116410/30631), [Greg Lever](https://askubuntu.com/users/697829/greg-lever), after clicking around I found what Greg mentioned:

1. Open Gnome Disks.
2. Choose/Click on the main physical hard drive in the left panel.
3. Click on the LUKS encrypted partition, in this example it is Partition 3:
   [image: Screenshot Gnome Disks]
4. Click on the edit icon (cogs, gear wheels) and choose "Change Passphrase".

If you get an **error**, close GNOME Disks and open it in a terminal:  `sudo gnome-disks`
(This helped [@ScriptAutomate](https://askubuntu.com/users/495729/scriptautomate), thank you for the tip.)

## Or using the command-line:

Here is the answer that worked for me, after [Hamish](https://askubuntu.com/users/150/hamish-downer) helped me to realize my typo.

**WARNING** (for **older** Ubuntu versions, newer (e.g. 19.04) should be [bug-fixed](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libblockdev/+bug/1837437) but be careful anyway): **If you only have one key and remove it before adding another, you will render your disk inaccessible after rebooting! This also means you can not add a new key anymore afterwards.** *Thanks [waffl](https://askubuntu.com/users/222816/waffl) and [khaimovmr](https://askubuntu.com/users/73022/khaimovmr) for these helpful comments.*

First, you need to find out **which is the encrypted LVM partition**, it may be sda3, but it can also be sda5 (default on Ubuntu LVM), sdX2, ...:

```
cat /etc/crypttab
```

To **add** a new password, use `luksAddKey`:

```
sudo cryptsetup luksAddKey /dev/sda3
```

To **remove** an existing password, use `luksRemoveKey`, by typing the passphrase to remove:

```
sudo cryptsetup luksRemoveKey /dev/sda3
```

**View currently used slots** of the encrypted partition (make sure at least one slot is shown):

```
sudo cryptsetup luksDump /dev/sda3
```

Cited from this [blog](http://blog.andreas-haerter.com/2011/06/18/ubuntu-full-disk-encryption-lvm-luks#tips_and_tricks). Thanks.

**Be aware:** [Flimm experienced](https://askubuntu.com/questions/109898/how-to-change-the-password-of-an-encrypted-lvm-system-done-with-the-alternate-i?noredirect=1#comment2030715_110195) that Ubuntu's system keyboard layout changed from Dvorak to Qwerty. You cannot see which keyboard layout you are using ([bug #1862656](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cryptsetup/+bug/1862656)) and you cannot choose to display the password ([bug #1862654](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cryptsetup/+bug/1862654)). Also, you only get three tries before being forced to wait for 60 seconds ([bug #1862660](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cryptsetup/+bug/1862660)). *Thanks [flimm](https://askubuntu.com/users/2355/flimm) for the helpful comment!*

Comment: does this imply you can have more than one password to unencrypt the disk?

Comment: You can. I tested it out

Comment: There are slots - eight of them I believe. Each slot is an unlock option. Could be 8 passwords if you wanted.

Comment: **WARNING** There should be a disclaimer above this answer that if you remove the only key before adding another, you will render your disk inaccessible after rebooting!

Comment: **WARNING** The disk is not only unusable AFTER THE REBOOT, when you've deleted the last key, but you CANNOT ADD A NEW KEYS AFTER THAT AS WELL!

Comment: After I did this, for some reason Ubuntu's system keyboard layout changed from Dvorak to Qwerty. It tooks me quite a while to figure out. It was a slow process as you cannot see which keyboard layout you are using ([bug #1862656](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cryptsetup/+bug/1862656)) and you cannot choose to display the password ([bug #1862654](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cryptsetup/+bug/1862654)). Also, you only get three tries ([bug #1862660](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cryptsetup/+bug/1862660)).

Comment: Thanks! Using Gnome Disks, I was given a permissions error until I closed it and opened it via `sudo gnome-disks` instead

Answer (score 31):

Download "Disks" from Software Manager. Run it. Select your encrypted device partition. Click gear icon. Select "Change passphrase". That's it

Comment: It's greyed out

Answer (score 23):

To see the slots used:

```
sudo cryptsetup luksDump /dev/sda5
```

And to find out which partition to use

```
cat /etc/crypttab
```

And if it is listed by uuid, use

```
ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid/{insert your uuid here}
```

Then use

```
sudo cryptsetup luksAddKey /dev/sda5
sudo cryptsetup luksRemoveKey /dev/sda5
```

or

```
sudo cryptsetup luksChangeKey /dev/sda5
```

and for faster reference (assuming only 1 entry in /etc/crypttab)

```
sudo cryptsetup luksAddKey /dev/disk/by-uuid/$(cat /etc/crypttab | sed -e "s|\(.*\) UUID=\(.*\) none.*|\2|g")
sudo cryptsetup luksChangeKey /dev/disk/by-uuid/$(cat /etc/crypttab | sed -e "s|\(.*\) UUID=\(.*\) none.*|\2|g")
```

Comment: +1 for explaining what to do when `cat /etc/crypttab` lists uuid.

Answer (score 15):

Without thinking I set the passphrase to be really long, and it became a pain to type. I ended up using the following to change it to something more manageable.

```
sudo cryptsetup luksChangeKey /dev/sda5
```

Answer (score 7):

The encrypted partition may well be using `/dev/sda5` (note the a in sda5) and that is the device you probably need to use (unless that is just a typo in your question).

However the encrypted device itself will have another name - something like `/dev/mapper/cryptroot`. For the device name you could:

- look in the file `/etc/crypttab` - this will have both the partition and the mapper name in it, but only for permanent partitions
- run `mount` and see what the mapper name is - this is useful when you have plugged in an encrypted disk via USB. (Though I'm not sure how you then find the actual underlying device name).

Answer (score 4):

I had issues locating partition name, so created this guide:

1. Locate your LMV partition

   ```
   # install jq if you don't have it
   sudo apt-get install jq

   # find LVM partition
   LVMPART=$(lsblk -p --json | jq -r '.blockdevices[] | select(.children) | .children[] | select(.children) as $partition | .children[] | select(.type == "crypt") | $partition.name')

   # check if it was found
   echo $LVMPART

       # (optional)
       # if above output is empty, locate it in a tree view using this command
       lsblk -p

       # partition `/dev/some_name` should be the parent object of the one with TYPE of `crypt`, set it
       LVMPART=`/dev/some_name`
   ```
2. Check LVM partition meta by dumping it

   ```
   sudo cryptsetup luksDump $LVMPART
   ```
3. Add new key (you can have multiple keys)

   ```
   sudo cryptsetup luksAddKey $LVMPART
   ```
4. After dumping it again, you should see multiple keys

   ```
   sudo cryptsetup luksDump $LVMPART
   ```
5. Delete old key if desired

   ```
   sudo cryptsetup luksRemoveKey $LVMPART
   ```

Answer (score 4):

On Ubuntu 18.04 run `gnome-disks` and you can point and click to change the passphrase for the encryption.