# luksOpen command context

Tags: encryption, uuid

When using luksOpen, does one specify the UUID and the PARTUUID. Which goes first?

On trying to post the above sentence, AskUbuntu robocop said it does not meet "our quality standards". I cannot be any more clear that the question as asked. Sorry to all Admins. It's taken me 8 weeks of daily researching encryption to get to a point where I can form my question. But for the sake of complying with AskUbuntu. Here goes nothing.

I have my /home on an external sata.

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 to a `ssd` using Ubuntu's installation time encryption. I was shown a 32 character passphrase and told to write it down. I did so. When I called Ubuntu's "Backups" and told it to restore it failed as the external drive has become encrypted. Even though I did not have the external `sata /home` powered up during the install. At one point in time, I was able to unlock (is that technically: unwrap?) the `/home`, but now I can't. Again, after 6 to 8 weeks of researching this, I believe I need the above short question answered.

I don't usually perform a "Restore", so I'm uncertain if it "didn't work as usual". The Backups have always written to the ext `dev`. And `Deja-Dup` runs a test on the backup set. I've never seen an error reported. I have a /home on an external drive. It is written by `deja-dup`. After I installed the `ssd`, and tried to "Restore", `deja-dup` said it could not find the place to restore from. I did nothing that I am aware of to encrypt the external drive. I may have had it turned on but don't 100% recall

```
cat /etc/crypttab 

cryptswap1 UUID=71335368-221f-4afd-9fde-f337dee8ee15 /dev/urandom swap,offset=1024,cipher=aes-xts-plain64
```

but the external device is (from `lsblk`):

```
/dev/sdb1: UUID="9deada4e-82ad-45fa-a1c6-a8e68d8b41f5" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="e1d12727-f8c8-47bf-be15-e7246d3dd0c4"
```

Again, I apologize to the Admins of AskUbuntu, and thank you to all the Linux Community for any help.

Comment: What does `When I called Ubuntu's "Backups" and told it to restore it failed as the external drive has become encrypted` mean...You encrypted then made backup, then tried to restore... Please write out the process till this current point so we can follow or I can follow. Again you could try both and which ever works is the answer but I believe its the `UUID`

Comment: No, I have always made weekly backups, using Ubuntu's "Backups".  There was an existing backup of /home on an external sata hdd.  This "backup" was kept on an external device and not powered on while the new ssd had Ubuntu 16.04.2 installed. After that, I tried to run Ubuntu's "Backups" and cause the backup to be "Restored" to the ssd from the external sata drive. "Backups" could not find a "location" (which in Ubuntu's "Backups" can be a folder or directory, Amazon's AWS, and other "locations") to restore from. When I looked in the external sata, I was surprised to see the encryption.

Comment: If i get you right you encrypted then ran backup, followed by restore but it didn't work as usual?

Comment: I don't usually perform a "Restore", so I'm uncertain if it "didn't work as usual". The Backups have always written to the ext dev. And Deja-Dup runs a test on the backup set. I've never seen an error reported. I have a /home on an external drive. It is written by deja-dup. After I installed the ssd, and tried to "Restore", deja-dup said it could not find the place to restore from. I did nothing that I am aware of to encrypt the external drive. I may have had it turned on but don't 100% recall. (I'm a 70-ish year old man). Thnx.

Comment: This might explain your situation: https://superuser.com/questions/330819/can-i-make-a-system-backup-encrypt-the-disk-and-restore-everything-with-ubuntu

Comment: Per this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/205240/how-to-open-encrypted-partition-knowing-the-passphrase, I'm trying:  cryptsetup luksOpen <device file> <device-mapper name>, but I can't figure out what <device file> <device-mapper name>  are to be. Reading the post at SuperUser, I can say I did not use TrueCrypt. At one time, I was at the point to do vgdisplay and lvdisplay and change those, but I wasn't able to get past mere mounting (/media/mark/UUID of external device (and not PARTUUID) of the partition where the backup is. (whew! that's a mouthful).

Comment: Please run `cat /etc/crypttab` and paste the output

Comment: mark@Lexington:~$ cat /etc/crypttab
cryptswap1 UUID=71335368-221f-4afd-9fde-f337dee8ee15 /dev/urandom swap,offset=1024,cipher=aes-xts-plain64             but the external device is (from lsblk): /dev/sdb1: UUID="9deada4e-82ad-45fa-a1c6-a8e68d8b41f5" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="e1d12727-f8c8-47bf-be15-e7246d3dd0c4"

Comment: Ok - device file is `UUID=71335368-221f-4afd-9fde-f337dee8ee15 `, device mapper name is : `cryptswap1`

Comment: Now run `lsblk -f` to what owns `UUID=71335368-221f-4afd-9fde-f337dee8ee15 `

Comment: /dev/sdc1 is the external drive I'm trying to access:   
 mark@Lexington:~$ sudo lsblk -f
[sudo] password for mark: 
NAME   FSTYPE LABEL UUID                                 MOUNTPOINT
sdb                                                             
sdc                                                      
└─sdc1 ext4         9deada4e-82ad-45fa-a1c6-a8e68d8b41f5 
sda                                                      
├─sda2                                                   
├─sda5 swap         71335368-221f-4afd-9fde-f337dee8ee15 
│ └─cryptswap1 -- FWIW I'm trying to unlock sdc1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64367/discussion-between-mark-preston-and-george).