# Preseed Ubuntu installation with full disk encryption

Tags: encryption, ubiquity, preseed

I am trying to set up Ubuntu full disk encryption using preseeding. I was able to set things up correctly following the preseed file presented [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Enterprise/WorkstationAutoinstallPreseed). But I do not want to provide the default password in the preseed file. Is there a way to let ubiquity fall to the screen that asks for the encryption passphrase just like it does when the username is not provided in the preseed file?

When I try to leave the passphrase option empty in the preseed file, I get an error in the installer saying "An error occured while creating the keyfile".

Answer (score 2):

I think the way to go here is to set the passphrase in the preseed. This way the disk is encrypted with a known passphrase. Then after the install. Prompt the user to "rekey". The Luks encryption scheme has a few passphrase slots by default. The one your setting up in the preseed can be removed as part of the rekeying action.

More here:

[How to change the password of an encrypted LVM system (done with the alternate Installation)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/109898/how-to-change-the-password-of-an-encrypted-lvm-system-done-with-the-alternate-i)