# Can't unlock disk sda5_crypt after upgrade to 18.04

Tags: boot, upgrade, keyboard-layout

After upgrading my Ubuntu MATE to 18.04, I can't login at the screen that says "Please unlock disk sda_crypt".

When I switch to a console-like screen by pressing ESC, I see the following messages.

---

```
Warning: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to device scanning.
Volume group "ubuntu-mate-vg" not found
Cannot process volume group ubuntu-mate-vg
Please unlock disk sda5_crypt
```

---

I suspect this may be keyboard layout issue because the password is still working - I could boot into UBUNTU 17.10 from a USB stick and open the hard drive from GUI using the password. I've been using UK layout, but perhaps the upgrade reset it to US one?

But unfortunately I can't find a way to change the keyboard layout without getting past this screen first.

Could anyone help?

**Update 1:**

I've checked the keyboard layout settings. They both indicate UK layout, which is what I need. Is there any other file I could check?

**Content of *`/etc/default/keyboard`***:

```
# KEYBOARD CONFIGURATION FILE
# Consult the keyboard(5) manual page.
XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBLAYOUT="gb"
XKBVARIANT=""
XKBOPTIONS=""
BACKSPACE="guess"
```

**Output of `setxkbmap -query` command:**

```
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     gb
```

---

**Update 2:**

I've just reinstalled version 17.10 and upgraded it to 18.04. And I noticed that the upgrade changed the keyboard layout at the crypt unlocking screen from **US to UK**.

So, contrary to what I thought, I guess my crypt password had been based on the US keyboard, and it didn't work after the upgrade because the keyboard layout switched to the UK one.

Comment: I'm assuming you have a UK keyboard and the system is using a US layout. I recommend that you print the current layout so you can have a guide and find the appropriate keys to type the password and then get into the OS and change it to what you need.  If this is not a layout issue, I have no idea how to help you.

Comment: Thank you Felipe for your comment. I've updated the question with the current keyboard layout settings. I still can't unlock the cryptsetup (and therefore cannot login because login screen comes after that) so will it be possible to change the keyboard layout from a live session?

Comment: If you can open the disk with a live USB (or going back to the previous version) you can add a 2nd password entry with  some layout- agnostic password, and use that until you have fixed everything.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, xenoid. That would have been a very good solution although this time I ended up reinstalling it. I'll try it with the next upgrade if the same thing happens.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for mentioning the keyboard issue for sd5_crypt after upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04.

I tried that before but you made me look at it again with more scrutiny. For me it wasn't about UK vs US keyboard layouts but realizing that for sd5-crypt I was still on an english layout which I mixed with German layout.

Looking up the keyboard maps in Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_and_American_keyboards

I transposed my passphrase into english-layout string and it worked for me.

STRANGE THING that this problem did not occur with previous version Ubuntu 17.10

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment, Oroy, and I'm sorry for not replying earlier. I'm kind of repeating what I said in my question, but that sounds similar to what happened to me. When I was reinstalling Ubuntu 17.10, the US keyboard layout was used for the crypt passphrase even though the on-screen keyboard (i.e. I could see what I was typing on screen) was a UK one. I realised this only after I upgraded to 18.04 again, when I had to type a US-to-UK-layout-converted passphrase to log in. Anyway, let's hope the next upgrade won't cause this.

Answer (score 1):

I guess two approaches could be tried. I cannot guarantee they will work because I haven't tried them - I ended up reinstalling Ubuntu before trying these.

## Approach 1 (if using a non-US keyboard layout)

Type your passphrase considering the following two scenarios **if, for example, you were using a UK keyboard layout**.

1. Your ***passphrase*** was created using the **US** keyboard layout,

   but now the ***keyboard*** is in the **UK** layout.
2. Your ***passphrase*** was created using the **UK** keyboard layout,

   but now the ***keyboard*** is in the **US** layout.

This approach is based on my guess from [oroy](https://askubuntu.com/users/829772/oroy)'s answer and also my experience while reinstalling Ubuntu 17.10 and upgrading it to version 18.04

## Approach 2

**Boot from a live USB stick or a CD** and **add a new passphrase to sda5_crypt** (and also remove old passphrase if you want). For how to do this, see https://askubuntu.com/a/110195/828323.

This approach is based on [xenoid](https://askubuntu.com/users/548230/xenoid)'s comment.