# passphrase/keyring management: 14.04 whole disk encryption

Tags: encryption, passphrase

With 14.04 whole disk encryption can one add multiple passphrases and/or revoke them ?

Comment: You should specify which kind of disk encryption protocol you're asking about. There's cryptoloop, dm-crypt, LUKS, TrueCrypt, …

Answer (score 3):

LUKS:

Basically as far as I know LUKS lets you modify 8 passphrase slots and you can do that with:

```
sudo cryptsetup luksAddKey <device>
sudo cryptsetup luksRemoveKey <device>
sudo cryptsetup luksChangeKey <device> 
sudo cryptsetup luksKillSlot <device> <key slot number>
```

LUKS stores slots as 0,1,2 etc. But I recommend you to be very careful with LUKS as you may lock yourself out. Please refer to manual of cryptsetup.

You may need to reboot the machine and try your new passsphrase as well before you remove the key.

[CryptSetup](http://code.google.com/p/cryptsetup/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions)

`Gnome-disk-utility` also lets you change the passphrases.

[image: Gnome]
[image: Gnome]

[Source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/95137/how-to-change-luks-passphrase)

Comment: How can i add different passkey in disk.so i can use both key to access that disk.

Comment: Luksaddkey is the command. Or you can do this in the GUI

Answer (score 0):

[EncryptedFilesystemHowto5](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedFilesystemHowto5)

That link provide everything about encryption.He asked about different (add multiple passphrase)