# How to change encryption password?

Tags: encryption

When I originally installed Ubuntu, I opted to have my hard drive encrypted, which is fine, but all of a sudden I can't seem to type my password.

After the third or fourth attempt I am finally able to type in my password correctly and then progress to the login, which then I have to type in the *same* password (three or four more times)...

Is it possible to change the encryption password?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/95137/how-to-change-luks-passphrase?