# Is it really possible to intrude a fully ENCRYPTED Hard Drive? (Encrypted since installation of ubuntu 18.04 OS)

Tags: password, encryption, security

So I`m using ubuntu 18.04 LTS almost on every machine that I use in my lifetime.. WHether for programming, storing sensitive information, financial transaction, entertainment so on and so forth!!..

so let me know is it possible (for hackers) to invade and get access over the files and data of my hard drive (every hard drive is encrypted during installation itself)

is there any other way in Linux to master encrypt (encrypt entire hard drive) for non-OS partitions and drives?..

Also, asking basic question, why it`s not possible to change encrypted passwords after installing OS?.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How secure is an encrypted LUKS filesystem?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/97196/how-secure-is-an-encrypted-luks-filesystem) -- The weakness is not with encryption, but how well you secure your credentials (in this case, your passphrase) Also.  You can change the passphrase.  See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/95137/how-to-change-luks-passphrase

Answer (score 2):

> so let me know is it possible (for hackers) to invade and get access over the files and data of my hard drive (every hard drive is encrypted during installation itself)

Yes. Disk encryption protects data at rest. It's of no use if an attacker gains access, e.g. via malware or security issues in software. It's also only as good as the master key.

> is there any other way in Linux to master encrypt (encrypt entire hard drive) for non-OS partitions and drives?

Sure. Truecrypt/Veracrypt, dm-crypt and luks are all different ways of doing this. But as far as I'm aware all are rather secure.